# How to take string input from file in assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have a file named `customer.txt`.

customer.txt

```
amin jamal
```

I need a sample code which takes string input(`amin`) from `customer.txt` file
and print it using c `printf()` function.

My code is

```
section .bss
s: resb 100

section .data

fmt: db "%s",10,0
name: db "customer.txt",0
mode: db "r+",0
fp: dq 0

section .text

global main
extern fopen
extern fgets
extern printf
main:


push rbp

mov rdi , name;
mov rsi , mode
call fopen
mov [fp] , rax
mov rdi , s
mov rsi , 7
mov rdx , [fp]
call fgets
mov rdi , fmt
mov rsi , s
call printf

pop rbp
ret
```

This can not take full string.

I am using NASM assembler. My OS is 64bit Linux.

I use nasm command for assemble, compile and run.

```
nasm -f elf64 file.asm
gcc file.o
./a.out
```

results -
`amin j`

Comment: What does _"can not take full string"_ mean exactly? What are some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: Do you mean that it takes at most seven (cfr `mov rsi , 7`) chars?

Comment: @Michael I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Can you add some error handling. I tried your code and it worked fine for me.

```
section .bss
s : resb 100

section .data
fmt  : db "%s",10,0
name : db "customer.txt",0
mode : db "r+",0
err1 : db "Failed To Open File", 10, 0
err2 : db "Failed To Read File", 10, 0

section .text
extern fopen
extern fgets
extern printf

global main

main:
    push rbp

    ; Open the file for reading
    mov rdi , name
    mov rsi , mode
    call fopen
    cmp rax, 0       ; Check for errors
    je .errfopen

    ; read first 7 characters from the open file
    mov rdi , s
    mov rsi , 7
    mov rdx , rax ; File Pointer
    call fgets
    cmp rax, 0    ; Check for errors
    je .errfgets

    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, s
    call printf

    pop rbp
    ret

.errfopen:
    mov rdi, err1
    call printf
    pop rbp
    ret

.errfgets:
    mov rdi, err2
    call printf
    pop rbp
    ret
```